# How to align correcly ExtJs grid

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have an ExtJs grid but the grid rows are not aligned correctly with the grid header. There is a little gap between the starting point and ending point of the grid rows

[image]

Some one who knows the reason for this, please help me.

Comment: You have to post the code for this grid. Also if you are using any css stylesheets that are not default, you have to post relevant sections.

Answer (score 3):

You should set `width` property as follows ( this is the set data width ):

```
{text: 'VARIANT', dataIndex: 'VAR', width: 73, align: 'center'}
```

If you want to set column header width, then :

```
{text: 'VARIANT', dataIndex: 'VAR', width: 73, align: 'center', columnWidth: 80}
```

Or, if you want to Autofit colums, then :

```
{text: 'VARIANT', dataIndex: 'VAR', flex: 1, align: 'center'}

// or set default for all columns
columns: {
items: [
    {
        text: "COLUMNA"
        dataIndex: "FIELDA"
    },{
        text: "COLUMNB",
        dataIndex: "FIELDB"
    }, 
    ...
],
defaults: {
    flex: 1
}
}
```